# Unable to find systems call similar to DisableThreadLibraryCalls for disable notification in Linux environment

Tags: c++, linux, mfc

While porting code base from MFC to Linux? Unable to find systems call similar to `DisableThreadLibraryCalls` for disable notification in Linux environment like `DisableThreadLibraryCalls`. What are best available systems to achieve similar kind of performance perceptive in Linux platform. Is it useful to use RTLD_LAZY flag or more. Please advice..

Comment: Have you actually observed any library loading notifications in Linux/posix environments? If not, just remove the `DisableThreadLibraryCalls` call.

Comment: I'm new to this stuff, just getting into. As per my understanding NO. Correct me, If I'm wrong?

Comment: I don't think the loader has notifications built-in so I would just remove the call.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Any good source to get into more in details? related to this kind of porting and performance improvement as Linux side...

Comment: Not really, but to go from MFC to Linux will likely require rewriting _a lot_ so perhaps the best way to go about it is to instead write the program from scratch and use the original MFC based program as inspiration only.

Comment: `DisableThreadLibraryCalls` is very specific to Windows, so the question doesn't make much sense. You need to tell us more, especially what kind of code/application is this? But as already mentioned, best is probably to rewrite the whole thing.

Comment: I have a old application which written in MFC class, Now porting to Linux (Redhat Enterprise Linux or Oracle Enterprise Linux), from DllMain in Windows calling         ```case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hinstDll);``` This function lets a DLL disable the DLL_THREAD_ATTACH and DLL_THREAD_DETACH notification calls. I would like to mockup same behavior on OLE. That was ask...I'm not sure about Notification on Linux side loader

Comment: Maybe porting via [Winelib](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winelib_User's_Guide) would be the easiest path forward.

Comment: `DisableThreadLibraryCalls` disables a feature present on Windows that doesn't exist in Linux. The port is thus to change `DisableThreadLibraryCalls` to nothing.